# how to install geometry_msgs on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberrypi, geometry-msgs, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can someone show me how to install geometry_msgs on raspberry Pi 2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255937/how-to-install-geometry_msgs-on-raspberry-pi/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2017-03-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raspet](https://answers.ros.org/users/29434/raspet/) on 2017-03-02**:
What is your operative system? I encountered lots of problems for raspbian and switched to ubuntu mate 14.04 and everything worked like a charm

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2017-03-02**:
I have Raspbian Jessie. But having many issues getting packages install. I'll use Ubuntu Mate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Download common messages from here: https://github.com/ros/common_msgs and place it in *src* folder. Then run catkin_make in your workspace. It will install all common message type including geometry_msgs. If you only want geometry messages then download the [*geometry_msgs*](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/tree/jade-devel/geometry_msgs) folder.

---

Originally posted by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) with karma: 96 on 2017-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3